# jquery/ajax- post an array (not empty) to a c# webservice's function

Tags: arrays, web-services, jquery

I try to pass an array contains two integers to a webservice's function:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public bool sample(int number, int[] numbers)
{
    return (numbers.Sum() > number);
}
```

I do it with jquery.ajax:

```
var arr = ['20', '89'];

$.ajax({ url: "Registration.asmx/sample",
    data: jQuery.param({ 'number': '300', 'numbers[]': arr }),
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data) {
        $('#result').html(data.toString());
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        $('#result').html(jQuery.param({ 'number': '300', 'numbers': arr }) + "<br/><br/>" +
                      thrownError + "<br/><br/>" +
                      xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

but I always get a server internal error about an empty array(I think)[image: none]

Answer (score 0):

try changing :

```
data: jQuery.param({ 'number': '300', 'numbers[]': arr }),
```

to:

```
data: jQuery.param({ 'number': '300', 'numbers': arr }),
```

**EDIT:**

You are stating that the method accepts GET requests:

```
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
```

But in the javascript you are using POST:

```
type: "POST",
```

change it to:

```
type: "GET",
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried it before, and it hasn't helped.

Comment: Did you try it with 'number[]' or 'numbers'?

Comment: bot 'numbers' and 'numbers[]'

Answer (score 0):

Now I see that I have to create somehow the following url:
Registration.asmx/sample?number=30&numbers=55&numbers=88
(numbers:30, numbers[55,88])

I know only one way how to do it: creating a string :/
Do you know a js/jquery method that can handle this issue? (jquery.param creates a url like Registration.asmx/sample?number=30&numbers[]=55&numbers[]=88 which is not acceptable..)